# Funny "thump" sounds sometimes at night, what could be the cause?

Tags: plumbing, central-heating, noise

I live in a 4-story townhouse that has a wood frame (no concrete except in basement) and was built in late 1980's.

Once in a blue moon, whilst laying on the bed at night, I have heard a rather loud thump sound come from somewhere in the house. Sometimes there is 2-3 sounds, with perhaps a 5-10 second interval.

The bedroom is on the second highest floor and the sounds were loud enough to make me think someone had broken into the basement. So I checked the house but did not see any evidence of anyone breaking in.

Anyway this house has air ducts embedded into wooden floors, so I wanted to ask if these sounds could be caused by e.g. warm air in the heating system expanding the floors? Or could it be something in the plumbing system that can cause this? We live in Massachusetts and the temperature has been in low 40's for some weeks now, maybe it is related to that somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If your basement has a honey bucket sump or water sump pump, what you might be hearing is it shutting off. I have both in my basement. The regular water sump (which gets water from the drain tile and from A/C) runs quite regularly, especially during the rainy season. It is rather noticeable when it runs and shuts off ... it's sounds off when shutting off, but not too badly. The honey bucket sump (sewer evac for basement bathroom and grey water) kicks on every now and again. When it shuts off, there is a large noticeable thump from it. I don't know how to fix the issue, but it does do it. I hardly pay any attention to it because it is a known sound in the house which usually doesn't happen very often.

Answer (score 0):

In my house, that's the fridge ending a compressor cycle. It has gotten much louder over the years, but since it still seems to run well and efficiently I haven't bothered trying to get it fixed.

If really concerned, spend a day or night triangulating on the noise to find its source,  and proceed from there.